# Matlab: How to find the right-most point of a white line within the imrect?

Tags: matlab

i've got a question regarding the imrect() function, which is part of the image processing toolbox in MatLab.
I'd like to find a starting point within an image with it's (x,y) coordinate.

I use the imrect function for setting a region to limit and specify the lookup area,
but I can't get the point where the ROI mask is getting back mapped to the original size of the image.

As you can see on the image there is a specified rectangle (cyan-colored), which I want to inspect for the white line, especially the nearest point to the right edge of the rectangle. I experimentated with only looking up on the last column of the rectangle, but as I mentioned before, the re-mapping onto the global image coordinates failed.
So in this example, the white point I'd like to get would be around (98,302)

[image]

The original (x,y) coordinates are relevant, so a cropping of the image to the rectangle is not acceptable.
So, do you have any ideas?
Thanks for any helping comments.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my gosh.
I should often go outside and take a big bag of air.
It really helps while stuck on a problem.

For all people with same issues, see the answer in the following part.

```
imshow(im);
h1 = imrect;
pos = getPosition(h1); % to get the current position of the rectangle
setPosition(h1,[pos(1) pos(2) 1 pos(4)]); %for just selecting one row of the rect
BW = createMask(h1); 
test = BW.*im; % get the masked content of the image
[x,y] = find(test); % find the non-zero element and return x and y
```